# Commit half of repo on one branch, rest on another

Tags: git, github, version-control, jekyll, github-pages

FYI: This is a weird request, but I feel this may benefit other people.

I'm using [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/) and [GitHub Pages](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/github-pages/) to publish a website. I don't have any problems with Jekyll, really. However, I do need to use [generators](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/#generators) to build a number of dynamic pages from a [data file](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/datafiles/). As you can see in the generators link, the blue box specifically says that Github actually doesn't support generators, meaning none of my generated files will actually be created by committing to GitHub. This sucks, but isn't the end of the world.

My current (very hacky) method is to build my site in a `jekyll` branch in my repo (so I can save my codebase), commit those files, copy the generated `_site` files into a temp folder, switch branches to my `gh-pages`, delete existing files, and copy the generated file from my temp directory into the repo and commit those files (so the site will exist publicly).

I hate this. I feel like there has to be a better way using `git` only. Anyone know how to do this so that I can commit only certain files to one branch and other files to another branch, but same repo? Also, if anyone has any better suggestions overall, I'd be more than happy to entertain them.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

That's the way [Octopress](http://octopress.org/) process Jekyll site : one branch for code and one branch for generated files. I sometimes use this method when I need plugins or Gulp/Grunt tasks. It's more elaborated than simply pushing to one branch but I don't feel it's 'hacky'.

I've made a rake task that helps automate deployment. You can find my [Rakefile here](https://github.com/djacquel/JekyllVersioningWorkflows/blob/master/Rakefile). All the instructions are in file's comments.

Comment: wow, this looks incredible. thanks! i will check this out and get back to you.

Comment: sooo it looks like it just deleted half of my files for no reason :\

Comment: yeahhh... so this ended up breaking my entire repo. thanks anyways.

Comment: yeah, unfortunately :\ it's ok, i blew it away and recloned it.